# Rails: How can I securely store and reuse passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, ssh, passwords

So I have an application that can automate execution of remote tasks on other servers. It does this by connecting to the server via SSH and executing the commands through that connection.

The problem I have is how to handle the usernames/passwords for these servers. In most cases I cannot setup cert based authentication for SSH and am stuck using user/pass. While I'd prefer not to store the passwords in the database in plain text, I don't know or understand a way that I can store the passwords encrypted, yet still allow the application access to the password for the purposes of authenticating with the remote server.
Is this something that is possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's possible, but to be honest I don't advise you to develop such a thing if you're not familiar with cryptography, keys management and many others security best practices related to your app and network architecture to be able to handle securely encryption / decryption of such sensitive information. (I'm saying this because from your question I understand that you know nothing about crypto, correct me if I'm wrong).

Just in case you need later a good key management service, AWS launched recently one: http://aws.amazon.com/kms/?nc2=h_l3_dm

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards AWS's service. I won't be able to use AWS here since the machines are all in a closed system without access to external networks. I freely admit to being far from familiar with cryptography and key management best practices outside of what common sense tells me. The only way I can see to implement the password encryption while retaining the application functionality would require me to store the key(s) on the application server, but doing that would appear to render the encryption redundant outside of just slowing someone down who wanted access to the passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use login by public/private key, not SSL certificate.
To do this, you just need generate keypair, and deposit your public key into file .ssh/authorized_keys on target machine(s).

If you have many accounts, and you would like to use some system for public key management, you can use Kerberos/LDAP solution, or [emcssh](http://emercoin.com/EmerCoin_and_OpenSSH) - decentralized bublic key infrastructure for ssh.

*DISCLAIMER: I am author of emcssh PKI system.*

Comment: I think something similar to this is what I'll be going with. When the user adds a new server I'll prompt them for username and password for one time use. We'll use that to connect to the device and install the public key into the .ssh/authorized_keys file and use that key for subsequent connections.

Comment: You can deposit your public key, together with some manual, on the your WEB-site, and lets user just create/fill file authorized_keys, when they create account for you. Just use your key size 4096 bits.